# Google Analytics subdomain filter is filtering out virtual page views

Tags: google, google-analytics, tracking, filtering

I have a reporting view setup with a filter to show only the traffic to the subdomain. I can see in realtime view that it is correctly showing only traffic to the subdomain. However, it seems that no virtual page views are getting through the to this reporting view.

If i view the standard unfiltered view I can see the virtual page views are firing correctly.

The filter I have is as follows:

- Predefined,
- Include Only
- Traffic to the hostname
- That contain
- xxxx.example.com

Answer (score 1):

By default, Google Analytics works with URLs without a Hostname. It's what they call **page**, which indicates the path of the page being accessed.

As you set up a view which filters traffic from the subdomain `xxxx.example.com`, when you generate the virtual page, it must follow that pattern in order to appear in the view:

```
ga('set', 'page', 'xxxx.example.com/virtual-page.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is that maybe the host name is not getting set correctly.   When you send the virtual pageview you could set it explicitly like this:

```
ga('set', 'hostname', 'xxxx.example.com');
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```